# pnp4nagios is not creating graph for new services / hosts

Tags: monitoring, mongodb, nosql, nagios

I have working nagios infrastructure with pnp4nagios. Last days I added new host nosql and alerts of mongodb which is installed there.

Host configuration:

```
define host{
        host_name               nosql
        use                     linux-server,host-pnp
        address                 xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
        }
```

Service configuration:

```
define service{
        hostgroup_name                  nosql-servers
        use                             generic-service,pnp-service
        service_description             MongoDB Connect
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_mongo_connect
        }
```

They seems to be configured in same way like the others one. However, when I am trying to access graph in pnp4nagios I got:

```
Please check the documentation for information about the following error.

XML file "/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/nosql/MongoDB_Connect.xml" not found. Read FAQ online

file [line]:
application/models/data.php [312]:
```

I am a bit help.

How I should activate new graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may lie in the output from your monitor check_mongo_connect.  Unless it is set up to send additional data, PNP will not be able to pick it up.  If you to see what you need to do, I'd look at the output for one of the plug-ins (via a shell command) that you are getting PNP data for.

See this for more information: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/perfdata.html

Comment: I added "-D" switch to check_mongodb.py and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a template to tell pnp4nagios how to handle the output (normal or perfdata) from the "MongoDB Connect" service; It doesn't magically create graphs for new/unknown check types.

[See the section on templates in the docs](http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/tpl)